# Text Value From HTML Into Javascript Var?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid, var

I would like to know if the following line is the correct way to take html and put it into a Javascript var as numeric value?

```
var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = Number(document.getElementsById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML);
```

Nevermind that the variable name has the word 'rounded' in it. The value that I am trying to put into this var is a 2 point float that has already been rounded and it exist as html.

Below is the line of HTML code that is referenced by getElementsById...

```
$<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating" class="priceDisplay">8.00</div>
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this seems right. You will need to check for `NaN`, unless you have validation in place that takes care of non-numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  Supposed to be getElementById, not Elements.  I created a little code to show you how it works.

Here's what the code looks like in this website's code displayer:

```js
function displayText(){

var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = Number(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML)

  alert(thePoolHeatingFeeRounded);
}
```

```html
<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating">8.01</div><input type="button" onclick="displayText()" value="Display the innerHTML of Pool Heating">
```

Comment: Great! Can you tell me why the .00 has been peeled off of the var?

Comment: I guess the Number() function requires me to specify 2 point floats?

Comment: The `Number()` function converts the string to function, and reduces it to the simplest form.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. How'd you get Number() to display the number as a 2 point float without adding any arguments?

Comment: What do you mean arguments?

Comment: Number() displays the number in it's simplest form.  That's all there is to it.  That's why I like it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63236/discussion-between-alex-williams-and-pianoman99).

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

`var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = Number(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML);`

You were calling `getElementsById` which is not correct (it is not plural), I changed it to `getElementById`

Tip: if you need to check whether the Number is valid you can use `!isNaN(thePoolHeatingFeeRounded)` or use a trick to turn it into a default number (such as 0 or -1) like this:

`var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = Number(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML) || 0;`

You can also use `parseFloat()`:

`var thePoolHeatingFeeRounded = parseFloat(document.getElementById("priceDisplayPoolHeating").innerHTML) || 0;`

Comment: Thanx for that info on parseFloat().